Confused about the Radon-Nikodym theorem applied to the counting measure
Sorry, I just need someone to clear up a confusion I have.
Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be any measure space, and let $\#$ be the counting measure on $X$. We have that
$$\#(A) = 0 \implies |A| = 0 \implies A = \emptyset \implies \mu(A) = 0.$$
Thus, we get $\mu\ll\#$ and the Radon-Nikodym theorem gives a function $f$ such that
$$\mu(A) = \int_A \ \mathrm{d}\#.$$
However, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$0 = \mu(\mathbb{Q}) = \int_{\mathbb{Q}}\ \mathrm{d}\# = \#(\mathbb{Q}) = \infty.$$
What am I doing wrong?

For any interval $I \in \mathbb{R}$ (or even countably infinite set), the counting measure is not $\sigma$-finite and hence you cannot apply Radon Nikodym Theorem. For any finite set, the derivate is simply $0$.

@sudeep5221 of course! Feel free to add that as an answer

The Radon-Nikodym Theorem requires the measure to be $\sigma$-finite. What you found is an example that shows that the hypothesis is crucial, as the counting measure is not $\sigma$-finite on any uncountable set. On a countable set, the Lebesgue measure is zero and so that RN derivative is zero.
